# Vaadin how to bind a FieldGroup with a DataField

Tags: java, vaadin7, datefield

I am binding some text fields with data from a table and everything seems OK!

But in two particular fields I need to use dates and so I altered the corresponding TextFields to DateFields so that it is more convenient to user to change dates.

The problem now is that I cannot bind the data from the table to these DateFields...

Any idea on that?

Comment: Why can't you bind them?

Comment: An error occurs in the value change listener when setting the itemDataProperty. One thing is that all other fields just use the text property but the DateFields are different.

Comment: I thought to try making a custom Converter but still the same error appears... I tried to use the book of Vaadin's and set a global ConverterFactory but I don't see the proper Application class...

Comment: Show your code and error stack trace.

Comment: I solved this by creating a Converter class to enable conversion from Date to String and vice versa. I didn't have to use a global ConverterFactory and I used the DateField's setConverter method. The reason I still get an error is because of a ComboBox that I use in the same way...